# If $f(x)-\nabla f(x)^Tx$ is bounded for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then is f(x) approximately affine?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This question start from the next simple proposition:

If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f(x)=x^T\nabla f(x)$, then there exists some constant vector $c$ such that $f(x)=c^Tx$.

The proof of the previous proposition is easy, because one can easily show that $\nabla f$ is differentiable with gradient $0$ everywhere. But then I am thinking about a possible generalization of it. Specifically, my question can be formulated as following:

If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(x)-x^T\nabla f(x)$ is bounded, which means that $\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to\infty}\frac{|f(x)-x^T\nabla f(x)|}{\|x\|}=0$. Is there a constant vector $c$ such that $\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to\infty} \frac{|f(x)-c^Tx|}{\|x\|}=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Choose $f$ such that $f(x) = \|x\|$ for $\|x\| \ge 1$. Then,
$$f(x) - x^\top \nabla f(x) = 0$$
for all $\|x\| > 1$.